# Outlook attachment names in DASL

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get a list of attachments in the Outlook table.

I have tried below code. It throws an error. Any help is much appreciated as I am new to DASL queries

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" &
                   " >= '" & Me.FrmDate.ToString & "' AND " &
                   "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" &
                   " <= '" & Me.ToDate.ToString & "'"


        'Do search and obtain Table on Inbox
        Dim oT As Outlook.Table = eFolder.GetTable(strFilter) 'PLEASE IGNORE eFolder as it is declared earlier in the code

        oT.Sort("[SentOn]", True)

        With oT.Columns
            .Add("SenderName")
            .Add("Subject")
            .Add("urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription")
            .Add("Attachments")
        End With
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the text of the error that it throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you cannot retrieve the sub-object (recipient and attachment) properties from a folder contents table. You may or may not be able to retrieve the recipient names (since they are exposed as `PR_DISPLAY_TO` /  `PR_DISPLAY_CC` / `PR_DISPLAY_BCC` properties), but there is nothing like that for the attachments.

The best you can do is filter the list down to only the items with attachments - use `PR_HASATTACH` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B`) MAPI property - and then loop through the returned items and process their `Attachments` collection.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only), you can create sub-restrictions on the message recipients and attachments using the `PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS` and `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` properties, but OOM does not expose these at all. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, its versions of [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).[Items](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find`/`Restrict` and [MAPITable.ExecSQL](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm#ExecSQL) allow to specify `Recipients`/`To`/`CC`/`BCC`/`Attachments` properties in the queries, but only in a `WHERE` clause.